# ODBC error when executed by SQL JOB AGENT

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I am getting an error when I try to execute my SSIS Package by the Job Agent.

If I run through Visual Studio it runs perfectly.

The error is:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ODBC Source returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

This ODBC is an "IBM i Access for Windows ODBC data source".

I have try to put the packages running at 32-bit. Change some parameters in my connection (that is a project parameter).

**Update:**

I had to change my queries and work with openquery. Just a note, get attention to numeric columns because I  was having problems with decimal values.

Comment: Did you put the packages in 32bits in Visual Studio, or did you set that option in the Agent?

Comment: I have do that in the Agent. In VB I do not get any error.

Comment: are the i Access ODBC drives installed on the server where the SSIS Package is deployed to?

Comment: Yes, right now is a dev server so the deploy has made on the same server.